# AWS Lambda Python 3.10 - No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am running a Lambda in AWS using Python 3.10 and trying to run some code that builds ssh key-pairs. I get the following error when running my function, can anyone identify how to resolve this?

**Error**

```
strap.py", line 39, in _get_handler
m = importlib.import_module(modname.replace("/", "."))
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/var/task/index.py", line 4, in <module>
import libraries.ssh as ssh
File "/var/task/libraries/ssh.py", line 3, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives._serialization import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py", line 11, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import HashAlgorithm
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py", line 10, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import openssl as rust_openssl
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Python API call failed', /github/home/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.18.3/src/err/mod.rs:790:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 60, in <module>
main()
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 57, in main
awslambdaricmain.main([os.environ["LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"], os.environ["_HANDLER"]])
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/__main__.py", line 21, in main
bootstrap.run(app_root, handler, lambda_runtime_api_addr)
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 389, in run
request_handler = _get_handler(handler)
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 39, in _get_handler
m = importlib.import_module(modname.replace("/", "."))
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/var/task/index.py", line 4, in <module>
import libraries.ssh as ssh
File "/var/task/libraries/ssh.py", line 3, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives._serialization import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py", line 11, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import HashAlgorithm
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py", line 10, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import openssl as rust_openssl
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
START RequestId: 96dc8ff0-12e4-4ba3-8b7a-f87a1aff3419 Version: $LATEST
RequestId: 96dc8ff0-12e4-4ba3-8b7a-f87a1aff3419 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

**Python Code Snippet**

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as crypto_default_backend
import paramiko
import io
import boto3
import json
```

**Pip command installing dependencies**

```
"pip3 install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -t ${path.module}/layer/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages -r ${path.module}/layer/requirements.txt"
```

**requirements.txt file**

```
paramiko
```

**Supporting Info**

- I am running the code that [AWS publishes](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-ssh-key-rotation/blob/master/lambda/ssh.py#L1-L39).  That is the full piece of code that I am using.
- I moved the dependencies to a lambda layer
- I am building the zip via a github action runner (Ubuntu)

Ive tried a few variations of addition additional libraries to requirements.txt such as cffi with no success.

Comment: You found any solution yet?

Comment: @Nabil I just added my answer.  Hopefully it gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and I found out that the issue was that the python version that I used to package the requirements on the AWS Lambda Layer was different than the one that the AWS Lambda uses.

Check which python version you are using to package the layer and if it's different from the one that the target AWS Lambda uses then you will need to change the version to the AWS Lambda Python version.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work but only under some specific conditions.

*First*, in my **requirements.txt** file I included the following:

```
cffi 
parami
```

*Second*, when creating the Layer for my lambda to use, I included some flags:

```
pip3 install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -t ${path.module}/my-lambda-layer-dir/python/ -r ${path.module}/my-lambda-layer-dir/requirements.txt
```

Finally, I deployed this using Github actions, which are using the default ubuntu-latest runner.

I explicitly set my Github action to use python 3.10:

```
  - uses: actions/setup-python@v4 
    with:
      python-version: '3.10'
```

Getting it to work with Github actions using python 10 was just a fluke because my Lambda is running python 3.9.  I suspect that there is no released version of the required packages for python 3.10 so its just picking up the latest at version 3.9.

I wrapped this all in Terraform to deploy it.  I could get it to work when building / applying was terraform via Github actions; it would not work when deploying via Terraform Cloud (my guess is some difference in the OS).

Comment: `--only-binary=:all:` did the trick for me! Thanks!